C# Problem with CancellationToken and Queue
I have a queue that contains items that I pass into a method to download something.
I would now like to ensure that a download that I want to cancel is also canceled. At the moment ALL downloads are canceled. What exactly am I doing wrong?
Many thanks
public partial class Service : IService
{
    #region private Variable

    private Queue<Item> _downloadQueues = new Queue<Item>();

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    private async Task Initialize(string traceID)
    {
        await Process(traceID);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Konstruktor 
    public Service()
    {
        string traceID = EX.GetTraceID();
        _ = Initialize(traceID);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methoden

    public async Task Add(string traceID, Item item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item is not null)
            {
                _downloadQueues.Enqueue(Item);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Error(traceID, $"AddToDownloadQueueAsync:: Item is null");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(traceID, ex, $"AddDownloadToQueue:: ");
            return;
        }
    }

    public async Task CancelDownload()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    public async Task Process(string traceId)
    {
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_downloadQueues.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    _waitTaskEventHandler.WaitOne(Constants.WAIT_FOR_CHECKQUEUE_IN_MS);
                    while (_downloadQueues.TryDequeue(out Item? Item))
                    {

                        Task? task = client.Download(traceId, Item, Item.CancellationToken);
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                    _waitTaskEventHandler.Reset();
                }

I have already tried to add a new cancelationtokensource inside the while loop at Process, but that doesn't work either.

Queue isn't thread-safe. You can use locks or, even better, a ConcurrentQueue or Channel. Locking just the dequeue operation doesn't protect from concurrent queue operations. Instead of using _downloadQueues.Count use only TryDequeue.

Where does Item.CancellationToken come from? To signal it, you need to find the corresponding CancellationTokenSource and call Cancel. To cancel individual items you need one CTS per item

@PanagiotisKanavos I have a Item Class:
public partial class Item: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public CancellationToken cancellationToken;

}

But where does that CancellationToken come from? One CTS for all? A separate CTS per item? If you have only one CTS for all items it's impossible to cancel just one

@PanagiotisKanavos I currently have an item class with a CTS. Now that I've read it, it makes sense why they are all canceled. Because I only have one CTS... right?
I am so new to this topic, please excuse my ignorance

You can check this link about the Cancellation in Managed Threads.

You seem to have associated each item with a (different) cancellationToken already. If these are cancelled correctly it might be as easy as changing the loop to
while (downloadQueues.TryDequeue(out var item))
{
    if(item.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) continue;
    try{
       await client.Download(traceId, Item, Item.CancellationToken);
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException){} // Assuming you intend for cancelled items to be ignored.
}

This should be sufficient for a single threaded scenario.
If this is used with multiple threads you should probably be using a BlockingCollection with GetConsumingEnumerable. Or one of the high level libraries for producer-consumer patterns, like DataFlow or Channels.

@Rafael why? that would cancel all downloads again, which is exactly what the OP doesn't want...

downloadQueues.Count is an expensive operation. TryDequeue alone can replace the Count then Dequeue.

@PanagiotisKanavos fixed, but .Count seem to be implemented as return _size; so I don't see why that would be expensive.
